# finding a point that has specific distances from 2 other points and a line using only a compass and straight-edge

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Is there a way to find said point, which lies on half-plane, such that it has a distance of ***n*** from line L, ***n-m*** from point ***A***, and ***n-2m*** from point ***B***, with both points ***A*** and ***B*** located on the same half-plane?

[image]

Comment: What is the context of this problem, where did it come up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that it always works. Intuitively, because we have three conditions on $P$ but the plane is only two dimensional.

Let the distances $m,n$ be given. Then $P$ must lie on a circle centered at $A$ with radius $n-m$ and simultaneously on a circle centered at $B$ with radius $n-2m$. So $P$ must lie on the intersection of these circles.

Depending on the distance between $A$ and $B$ and depending on $m,n$ the circles intersect (as usual) in zero, one or two points. This does not leave enough freedom of choice to ensure that the distance between $P$ and $L$ is $n$. This only happens in certain cases.

Comment: what other parameters would be needed then? Would a single solution be possible if the distance between A and B as well as their distance from L was given?

Comment: You can develop the general situation if you introduce coordinates and formulate the conditions as equations.

Comment: If the distance of $A, B$ from $L$ and the distance between $A$ and $B$ are given (i.e. the whole situation is uniquely determined up to translation & rotation) then it is possible to tell whether a point $P$ exists.